# Calling oracle stored proc from .net and getting PLS-00201:

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I am not sure what is going on here.  All of a sudden I am having a hard time calling stored procs that used to be called pretty easily.  I get that above exception.

When I call them in sql developer they work just fine.  Do I need to update a connection string or a dll or something?

**UPDATE: CODE ADDED**

```
        if (implemtation == 1)
            sProc = "XXX.XXXXX";
        else if (implemtation == 2)
            sProc = "xxx.xxxxx";
        else
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error Determening stored Proc... Stored Proc: {0}",(sProc == "" ? "Empty" : sProc)));
        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACODBConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
            {
                ///Not so simple getting Oracle Data back into .Net... However, these code sections do it...
                ///Consider placing this section into its own method for more a object oriented application... Little time to consider that now however
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sProc, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    OracleParameter inputParm = new OracleParameter("XXXXIn", OracleDbType.Decimal);
                    OracleParameter inputParm2 = new OracleParameter("XXXXIn", OracleDbType.Decimal);
                    OracleParameter inputParm3 = new OracleParameter("XXXXIn", OracleDbType.Decimal);
                    inputParm.Value = Double.Parse(PopID);
                    inputParm2.Value = Double.Parse(History);
                    inputParm3.Value = Double.Parse(isActive);
                    OracleParameter outRefParam = new OracleParameter("cur_out", OracleDbType.RefCursor, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(inputParm);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(inputParm2);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(inputParm3);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(outRefParam);
                    adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    acoData = SerializeOracleData(ds);
                }
            }
        }
```

This same code was working but a few days ago.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Also, it would help to see the full error message, not just the error code ...

Comment: Make sure whatever database schema you connect to Oracle with from .net still has the appropriate roles/privileges.

Comment: The code is very specific, I don't think actually viewing it will provide any more insight... But fine.